# jquery click with nested div

Tags: jquery

I have a div and when I click, it opens a menu. In that div i have a nested div, and when I click on, it opens the same menu which is also logical.

Now I want when I press the nested div it doesn't open the menu.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bind a `click` event handler to the inner `div` and [stop the propagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) of the event there:

```
$("#innerDiv").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

That will prevent the event from bubbling up to the parent element, where it would cause the click event handler bound to it to fire.

Comment: Do you have to handle IE with `e.cancelBubble = true` as well, or does jQuery handle this?

Comment: @peirix - jQuery normalises the event object so you don't need to worry.

Answer (score 0):

Use [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) to prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree.

Answer (score 0):

Use [event.stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) or [event.stopImmediatePropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/) to prevent the event from bubbling.